# Can two SAPs including their Private subdomain, asset branding, and RMM be applied selectively to their child BUs?

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, sender-authentication-package

My use case and question are as follows:

Given the following SFMC Tenant/Enterprise Architecture:  Parent BU --> Child BU #1, Child BU #2, Child BU #3...

I am aware that one SAP (and its features - Private Subdomain + RMM + Asset Branding/Authorization) can applied to just the Enterprise (Parent BU), Enterprise (Parent) BU + all of the Child BUs, or just a singular Child BU throught the MID Reference.

My question is if the Original SAP (and feature components) is applied to JUST the Child BU #1, can a second and subsequent SAP be purchase (with the Private Subdomain + feature components) be applied selectivelty to the Enterprise (Parent) BU as well as the Child BU #2 while not affecting the SAP of Child BU #1?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply one SAP per one BU, or if you apply SAP to Parent BU, you can share it with selected BUs.

So in your case, apply the SAP that needs to be shared to Parent BU and share it with selected Child BUs, and for the other BU that needs a separate SAP, purchase a separate SAP and apply to that one Child BU only.

Not entirely explained below, but for reference:

> **A business unit only supports one SAP for branding purposes.** Therefore, view-as-webpage, links and images can only point to one
> domain. Accounts can have multiple Private Domains for Email sending
> on a single business unit for use as from addresses only. If you send
> from multiple From Addresses, the view-as-a-webpage, links and images
> point back to the SAP custom domain. **In certain scenarios, SAP can
> be shared across multiple accounts in the same environment. Create a
> support case to review your specific scenario. Reference the MIDs
> involved and the original SAP configuration case number in your
> support case.**

Link: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_sender_authentication_package.htm&language=en_US&type=5

Contact your AE or support to discuss details.